# Cannot redeclare Cpages::edit_galleries_picture()

Tags: codeigniter, debugging

How can I fix the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Cpages::edit_galleries_picture() in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\masterlinkci2\application\admin\controllers\Cpages.php
>   on line 476

```
A PHP Error was encountered
```

**Severity:** `Compile Error`

**Message:** `Cannot redeclare Cpages::edit_galleries_picture()`

**Filename:** `controllers/Cpages.php`

**Line Number:** `476`

**Backtrace:**

**The url:** http://localhost/masterlinkci2/admin/index.php/cpages/edit_galleries_picture/21

**Line 476:**  `public function edit_galleries_picture() {`

From Comment

```
public function edit_galleries_picture() { 
    $gallery_id = $this->uri->segment(3); 
    $data['pictures'] = $this->Mpages->call_gallery_pictures($gallery_id); 
    $this->load->view('editgalleries', $data); 
}
```

Comment: post your code ....

Comment: Line 476:

    public function edit_galleries_picture() {
      
      $gallery_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
      
      $data['pictures'] = $this->Mpages->call_gallery_pictures($gallery_id);
      
      $this->load->view('editgalleries', $data);
      
     }

Comment: your error suggests that you have declared public function edit_galleries_picture() twice which is not possible in php. Please check for that if not found then post full code of your controllers..

Comment: Re edit your question with code by clicking on edit button below tags

Answer (score 0):

This error showing because you already have function `edit_galleries_picture()` in controller `Cpages`.

To fix this error, make sure you don't have duplicated function. You can rename the function `edit_galleries_picture()` to something different, or you can combine the code into one function.